# What is the regular expression in LEX to match a string NOT starting with newline

Tags: regex, lex

I want to know the regular expression in lex to match a string which does not (start the line and is followed by optional white spaces followed by "a="). I am trying to parse a language with the following types of lines:

```
     a=some value
     b=some value
```

The strings "a=" (b=, etc.) can be preceded by white spaces and followed by another string without any white spaces after the = and upto newline. For example:

```
     a=123 abcde
```

Here "123 abcde" is the value. 
Problem is that I may encounter, at least in theory, the following

```
     a=123 a=
```

Or worse:

```
     a=a=
```

Where the first a= is the key and the second a= is now part of the value and not the key attribute. How do I distinguish the first a= token from the second?

I can match the key "a=" with the following which handles leading whitespace:

```
    ^[ \r\t]*"a="
```

But how do I match the second string? I need a regular expression of the type that says match a string that does NOT (start the line and is followed by optional whitespaces followed by a=) and extends upto newline character. The main trick is to avoid the expression matching the attribute a= also.

Comment: @wp78de Thanks but unfortunately it does not even compile in lex. For starters, the ^ at the start means starting the line and that is precisely what I do not want. The ^ has a different interpretation in most regular expressions. In Lex it negates only in a class of characters (for example, [^a-z]) otherwise interpreted as beginning of line (just as $ signifies end of line).  There are other syntactical issues.

Comment: Arguably, flex is not the ideal tool for this problem, but I don't know exactly what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a start condition to create a different lexical context for the input after the `=`.

Lex works best with a language in which tokenisation is not context-dependent (most programming languages but few ad hoc interchange formats). But start conditions are manageable if you don't have too many contexts to juggle.

See [the manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Start-Conditions.html#Start-Conditions) for details and examples.

Simple example:

```
%x RHS
%%
[[:space:]]+  ; /* Ignore leading white space and blank lines */
a=            { BEGIN(RHS); return TOKEN_A; }
b=            { BEGIN(RHS); return TOKEN_B; }
.*            ; /* Ignore other input. Should do something else */
<RHS>.+       { yylval = strdup(yytext); return VALUE; }
<RHS>\n       { BEGIN(INITIAL); }
```

Note: The RHS rules send nothing if there is no value. That shouldn't be a problem for a parser but if it is, you can fix it reasonably easily.

Comment: Support for start conditions opens a lot of possibilities that otherwise would be  very difficult or impossible to implement. Thanks for showing the way...